# What's the equation of this graph? High school Maths.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What's the equation of this graph?

[image]

It's driving me mad, I can't remember what the equation of this graph was like.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [The bell curve?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

Comment: something like $f(x) = 2 \cdot \exp(-x ²)$?

Comment: Do you have any answers to choose from?

Comment: Thanks Jan! Yeah it was something along that...! Now I can sketch the derivative.

Comment: @TheBucketHatCat: If you're only sketching the derivative, then you don't really need to know the equation.

Comment: Hey Blue, I'm curious to know that - my method was to think of an equation of a similar graph and from there find the rough sketch of the derivative. A name of your method or some keywords I can google would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @TheBucketHatCat: (Be sure to put "@" before a name to get someone's attention.) There's no name for my method; it's just derivative sketching. Ask yourself a series of questions; here: What does the slope of the graph *look like* at $x=0$? at $x=1$? at $x=-1$? at really large positive $x$? at really large negative $x$? Also, what can you say about the slopes in general for all positive $x$? for all negative $x$? Plot the slope values you estimated, and simply connect the dots in a manner consistent with the other observations. It's a *sketch*, so precision doesn't matter.

Comment: @Blue Thanks for the explanation, it all makes sense now, how the steepness of the gradient determines the graph of the derivative, I feel stupid that I didn't understand that. Oh and I remembered where I've seen the graph, it was the derivative of inverse tan function.

Comment: *A name of your method ...* --- A google-image search for ["graph of derivative"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22graph+of+derivative%22&tbm=isch) leads to a lot of helpful web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, so something along the lines of
$1/x^2+1$, or $1/e^{x^2}$.

The question was to draw the *derivative of the graph:*

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To be precise, what you linked is not 'a derivative of the graph' but rather a graph of a derivative function of the (given) graphed function. In short, it's a derivative's graph, but not _a_ derivative _of_ the graph. :)

Comment: @CiaPan Now that's just being pedantic

Comment: @PineappleFish Precisely.

Comment: @CiaPan Each graph corresponds to a unique graphing of a function and vice versa, so they may practically be considered the same right? The picture is just an identical manifestation of the rigorous "set-theoretic defined" function, no? This is actually a insanely interesting point

Answer (score 0):

You can sketch the derivative *without* the function's equation. Let's call your function $f$. It is 'nearly constant', slowly growing for negative $x$-es of big modulus, so $f^\prime$ is small potitive there.

Close to $x=-3$ your $f$ grows up faster and faster, so $f^\prime$ grows.

Approximately at $x=-1$ the function growth ratio is the biggest (its graph is steepest there), hence the maximum of the derivative.

The graph's slope seems close to $1:1$, an angle to the $X$ axis close to $45^\circ$, so the maximum value of the derivative is about $1$.

Then $f^\prime$ fals down to zero at $x=0$, because $f$ has a maximum there.

This is not a flat maximum, more like a vertex of parabola, so $f^\prime$ decreases linearly there.

A symmetric behavior of $f$ on the positive side implies a symmetric behavior of $f^\prime:$

[image]

Comment: Hey CiaPan, thanks for such a comprehensive and clear answer!

Comment: Reading it over and over to understand it fully